# Can't access jquery plugin's external function when plugin created inside event

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-plugins, prototype

I can't seem to access a plugin's function that was created inside a click event.
After the plugin is created I create another button that normally would use a plugin's external function but there seem to be no way to aproach the fuction. 
I had no problems accessing the function when the plugin was created during a document.ready event.

Any ideas?

```
var pluginHolder = $('<div/>'); //just in case this was the issue
$("body").on("click","#profile_plugin",function(e)
{

pluginHolder = $('<div/>',{id:"coverCanvas"}); //Holding external button and plugin in a div
abutton = $('<button/>',{class:"buttonis"});
plugin = $('<div/>');

plugin.testClass({
    c1:2,
    c2:"ffffff",
    c3:940,
});
//works fine (plugin renders and fully functional)

plugin.appendTo(pluginHolder);
abutton.appendTo(pluginHolder);
pluginHolder.appendTo($(".container"); //Works  

console.log(plugin.testoutput()); //Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
abutton.on("click",doStuff);

function doStuff(e)
{
    console.log(plugin.testoutput()); //Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
    console.log(plugin[0].testoutput()); //Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
}

});
```

Comment: There is no function `testoutput` in your code.

Comment: Yes. I did not include the prototypes functions in the code. TestOutput() is a testing function of the prototype class object "TestClass"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution so I will just post it here for future reference:

```
var coverCanvasObj = null;
var divContainer = $('<div/>');
coverCanvasObj = divContainer.testClass({
    option1:2,
    option2:tru
});
```

So I just needed to access the testClass object outside the render/container Div.